# add/remove shadow via css+javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shadow

I have a page with a lot of Div's, and I am using the panzoom jquery script. In order to speed up the page, I would like to disable the shadow on the divs if the page is zoomed out above a specified value, and enable the shadows if the page is zoomed in. currently I have this code, that is beeing called every 0.5 seconds:

```
function shadow()
{
var $panzoom = $('.panzoom').panzoom(); 

var matrix = $panzoom.panzoom("getMatrix");
$("#zoomf").html(matrix[0])

//if zoom is bigger than 0.35 enable shadows

if (matrix[0] > 0.35)
{
    var $elements = $('.machinebox').addClass('shadow');
    var $elements2 = $('.playerbox').addClass('shadow');
}
else
{
    $elements.removeClass('shadow');
    $elements2.removeClass('shadow');
}   
}
```

The problems I am facing are basically two:

1) the var $elements does not exist Always, it only exists as long as the shadow exists..  thus, if I zoom out, it removes the shadow and then generates a error: 
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'removeClass' of undefined or null reference
de (282,3)

2) when it adds/removes the shadows it freezes for about one second. can this be avoided somehow?

Comment: You’re misunderstanding how variables work. `var $elements` can only be _one_ thing, not two. Declaring `$elements` twice is a mistake. `$elements.removeClass('shadow');` twice will do the same thing twice to _the same element_.

Comment: You can do something like this `$('.machinebox, .playerbox').toggleClass("shadow", (matrix[0] > 0.35))`

Comment: Xufox thanks, you are right, that was a mistake, updated the code.

Comment: @Titus this works like a charm thanks! can now something be done to solve point 2 also?

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing that, it probably takes some time to get the matrix. You're calling `panzoom()` twice. I think you can get the matrix directly using `var matrix = $('.panzoom').panzoom("getMatrix");`

Comment: the time is due to the fact that the shadow is added to over 2000 divs. on a smaller version there is no delay. now i would need a way to add the shadow in a non locking way, maybe with lower priority compared to the zooming? or add it in blocks of 100 divs instead of all at once? or even better only the visible divs?

Comment: @Titus adding :visible to your code solves both problems! ´please post it as answer so i can mark it as accepted.. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is caused because the variables `$element` and `$element2` are only declared and initialized when the condition is `true`. The second one seems to be caused because there are a lot of elements which have the classes `machinebox` and `playerbox`.

You can fix both of them by using something like this:

```
function shadow() {
    var matrix = $('.panzoom').panzoom("getMatrix");
    $("#zoomf").html(matrix[0])
    $('.machinebox:visible, .playerbox:visible').toggleClass("shadow", (matrix[0] > 0.35))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For point 2 since you've solved point 1.
the function is running every 0.5 seconds, this is probably why you get that delay.
try pausing it until the next time the user zooms (idk if the library you're using allows you to detect such events)

Comment: the user is constantly zooming. the timer just checks at what zoomlevel it is right now.. so while zooming in, it locks, adds shadows and then continues the zooming.. that lock is what causes the trouble.

Comment: OH I see, there sure are lots of divs that are being changed here then...